# Destroy camera in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, air, camera

I am using the Camera on Flash, but when I finish to use, now can I "destroy" the camera object for improve the application performance?

```
private var camera_atual:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
private var video_camera:Video = new Video(820, 546);
camera_atual.setQuality(0,100);
camera_atual.setMode(550,480,30,true);
video_camera.attachCamera(camera_atual);
this.palco_mc.addChild(video_camera);
```

Comment: removing the video from the display list, setting it and the video to null should make it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Video.attachCamera()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Video.html#attachCamera%28%29) - "To drop the connection to the Video object, pass null."
The camera itself should be destroyed manually :)